# What determines if a variable is exogenous or endogenous in a model?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics

Question above, I have a very rudimentary understanding of econometrics.

Comment: lucho's comment: possible duplicate of my comment >:((((( .... :P

Comment: @luchonacho Thanks for the heads up on the dupe. I thought preferences was rather a separate topic.

Answer (score 0):

An endogenous variable is one whose value determined within the model. Exogenous variables are those variables whose values are determined by influences outside the model.